# SQL client like sequel pro for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

Hi I need to connect to a remote SQL Server database and I am not able to connect to it using Sequel pro, I have checked the connection using telnet and it is there. I also don't have windows OS so I cant install SQL Server.

Is there any work around for that? BTW I am using mac os

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SQiurreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/). It's a free, java-based GUI to many different databases. However, to use with SQL Server, it won't work out of the box. You need to get the [JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774) and add the path of the driver that you just downloaded to the definition of the driver in SQuirreL.

I use this to connect from my Mac to 2005 and 2008R2 SQL servers.